# Why isn't Google Fit returning all weights?

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit, google-apis-explorer

I am using an android app that retrieves a user's weight(s) for a given time range. The user can manually sync it for a given day and it will use mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00 and mm/dd/yyyy 23:59:59:999. In most cases this works correctly, however I have a workflow that seems to break it. I have a Wifi scale which I will weigh myself on, and then I have those weights synced to MyFitnessPal. I then have MyFitnessPal synced to Google Fit. This integration seems to work, as my weight is correctly displayed in Google Fit. However, MyFitnessPal seems to only save the date of the weighing and not the time. When I run the manually sync process for this android app on the same day that the weighing happened it does not return the weight.

I've tried to get the data from both android and the Google API Explorer. I can get past weights by changing my startTimeMillis, but I can't get the weight for the current date. It's as if the weight on the phone hasn't synced with the Google Fit data store, but even if that was the case I'd expect the android app to retrieve the weight.

Java code:

```java
DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT, DataType.AGGREGATE_WEIGHT_SUMMARY)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startMillis, endMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .build()
```

API Explorer call:

```xml
{
 "aggregateBy": [
  {
   "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight"
  }
 ],
 "endTimeMillis": "1560488399999",
 "startTimeMillis": "1560402000000"
}
```

My results from the API Explorer are here:

```xml
{
 "bucket": [
  {
   "startTimeMillis": "1560402000000",
   "endTimeMillis": "1560488399999",
   "dataset": [
    {
     "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight",
     "point": [
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I would expect a weight to be listed as there exists a weight for that startTimeMillis (1560402000000 milliseconds since epoch is Thursday, Jun 13, 12:00 AM local time) property in my [Google Fit app](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipONZOOJimHSMOD-c6w7a467cTQgnVcpKGdyEX4h66_HD9x3MjVfOwIcGfX8W7nWLg?key=djJlcVpsbU5jemRsQ2tLREtnYlZMRlZRNUtHNG53). The date for the weight listed is Thursday, Jun 13, 12:00 AM, however the API Explorer returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

That returns max, min and average. If you need to return all of them then user "read(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT)" instead of "aggregate"